# learning AngularJs : ng-model does not binding into View

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am very new to angularJS and you can say that this is my first day using angularJS.

it seems silly BUt i am trying to do some basic stuff which is not working somehow.

I have a text box in which if you enter 1234, `Count` should be `555` OR if you enter any number it should be `550` and i am putting `1234` on page load so it is showing me `555` BUT when i change value in textbox, `Count` is not changing.

```
<div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="prCtrl">
            Enter Product ID to get the reviews details
            <input type="number" ng-model="productId" required />
            <br />
            Total Review Count = {{ Count }}
        </div>
</div>

function prCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.productId = 1234;
    if ($scope.productId === 1234) {
        $scope.Count = 555;
    } else {
        $scope.Count = 550;
    }
}
```

how can i change `{{ Count }}` depending on the value entered in textbox.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to subscribe to the model change and carry out your logic there:

Controller:

```
function prCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.productId = 1234;
    $scope.$watch('productId', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if (newValue === 1234) {
            $scope.Count = 555;
        } else {
            $scope.Count = 550;
        }
    });
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="prCtrl">
        Enter Product ID to get the reviews details
        <input type="number" ng-model="productId" required />
        <br />
        Total Review Count = {{ Count }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tested that, and it appears to do what you want.

And a final note - you mention you are new to angular - I would highly recommend egghead.io 's sessions on AngularJS ( https://egghead.io/lessons ). They are good at getting you up to speed with AngularJS :)

Comment: sorry, i did not get you. it might be i explained my question poorly. let me edit my question

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a function, without watching the value using **$watch**

```
function prCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $scope.productId = 1234;

    $scope.getCount = function() {
       if ($scope.productId === 1234) {
          return 555;
       } else {
          return 550;
       }
    }               

}
```

view:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="prCtrl">
        Enter Product ID to get the reviews details
        <input type="number" ng-model="productId" required />
        <br />
        Total Review Count = {{ getCount() }} // replaced with function call
    </div>
</div>
```

This function gets called when ever a model is changed in the scope, so it will always update your value